# Installing Maven 3 on Windows 7

Tags: maven-3

When I type "mvn --version" or "mvn -version", I always receive error "mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

SO: WIN 7 64 bit

Maven directory:
`C:\Users\xxx\Documents\work\apache-maven-3.0.5`

In the system evironment variables I've set

M2_HOME = C:\Users\xxx\Documents\work\apache-maven-3.0.5

M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

PATH = %JAVA_HOME%/bin;%M2%

Can anyone see what i'm not doing right or what else i need to do to be able to use the mvn command, please and thank you.

Comment: Dunno if this is a cause, but you're using a forward slash in your PATH definition.  What if you tried %JAVA_HOME%\bin instead of %JAVA_HOME%/bin?  Also, because JAVA_HOME has spaces in it, try putting the path declaration in quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the User variable as M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-2.2.1
system variable : Edit the "path" variable add 
%M2_HOME%\bin; (or) 
C:\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin;

Close your command prompt and try again with 'mvn -version'

Comment: I' ve changed Maven directory: C:\apache-maven-3.0.5 and I've reinstalled JDK in c:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21  In the system evironment variables I've set M2_HOME = C:\apache-maven-3.0.5 M2 = %M2_HOME%\bin JAVA_HOME = C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21 PATH = %JAVA_HOME%/bin;%M2%

Comment: the result is    
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (2013-02-19 14:51:28+0100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_21, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre
Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
"cmd" non è riconosciuto come comando interno o esterno,
 un programma eseguibile o un file batch.

Answer (score 0):

it only needs to add "%M2_HOME%\bin" to system variables:Path

*from user2344797 answer*